# how to get value from ()=>Promise.resolve(value)?

Tags: javascript

I get a function a,
let a = () => Promise.resolve(value);

How could I get value out of a?

`let a = () => Promise.resolve(value);`

Comment: `a().then(val => console.log(val))`

Comment: Any basic promise tutorial will show you how. What did you try that isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

`a` it's just a promise find any basic tutorial about javascript Promises

Use this syntax if you are in `async` function

```
const value = await a();
```

OR simply :

```
a().then(value => console.log(value)) ;
```

Comment: One trick is to write ‘(async function() { ... })();’ replacing the ... with all code you would normally write. That resolves the issues found with promise land and allows await to work how you expect it in other languages.